# Form Validation With jQuery

Tags: jquery

Well, i have a problem validating a form with jQuery. I'm Not using any validation Framework (Such as http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation), because i need to do this without any Pre-Builded Solution (It's an user requirement, Strange, by the way). I Have a Textbox, And I Need to Validate Any String, but, that string has no numbers or Special Characters (Such as !"·$%&/()=;,:.-_), It's a Person Name. This is My Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var onlyChars = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
      var onlyNums = /^[0-9]+$/;
      var mail = /^[^0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[@][a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[.][a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
      var name = $("#txtname");
      function validateName()
      {
        if (name.val().length > 25)
        {
          alert("Too Longer");
          return false;
        }
        else if (name.val().match(/^[A-Za-z]+$/))
        {
          alert("Error, Pattern Doesn't Match");
          return false;
        }
        else
        {
          return true;
        }
      }
      $("#submitform").submit(function(){
        if (validateName())
        {
         return true;
        }
        else
        {
          return false;
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

The First Validation It's Ok (If I Write More Than 25 Characters, The Alert is triggered and the submit event is aborted), But, the second validation doesn't do it. In This case happens two events:

1. The Field, having Not-Allowed Characters "Pass" the validation and the form is submitted.
2. The Field, having only the allowed Characters Don't Pass the validation and the form isn't submitted.

I've Checked everything, and the "Two Issues" are completely Random.

Can You give me some Help?

Thanks a Lot!

PS: Sorry for the English, I'm not a "Native-Speaker"

Comment: It's okay to admit it's homework.

Comment: uh, please christ don't mix languages in your code? :< either go all-in spanish or all-in english. also, abbreviations are evil

Comment: @mootinator Sorry But No, This isn't Homework... :/

Comment: Okay, in that case I want to meet this person who thinks it's okay to use jQuery, but doesn't want to you use a pre-built solution specifically for validation so I can slap them. :)

Comment: @Nico My Apologies for the multiple mistakes... Corrected and simplified. Thank You!

Comment: @mootinator Sadly, I'm working on this way, and you should check the HTML of this file... It's terrible, but, no way. I'm Trying to get this done. Also, the rest of the code isn't mine, this is a program developed few months ago by other person, and i'm only a student... It's a valid explanation? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'll bite.

Look closely at this code:

```
    else if (name.val().match(/^[A-Za-z]+$/))
    {
      alert("Error, Pattern Doesn't Match");
      return false;
    }
```

That reads:  If name matches the pattern tell the user it doesn't and don't submit.  You want to inverse that:

```
    else if (!name.val().match(/^[A-Za-z]+$/))
    {
      alert("Error, Pattern Doesn't Match");
      return false;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, i missed the "!", but, "it's the same", in terms of result. I don't know why, but, gives me the same result, sometimes the form it's submitted with the special characters, and sometimes stops the execution, but, in this case the program blocks the "good expresions". E.g: I write "Foo Bar" in the textbox, and the script triggers the alert saying "Error, Pattern Doesn't Match".

Comment: var name = $("#txtname"); should be inside the validateName function.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is *saying* ==>
If name matches correctly, **say** *"pattern doesn't match"*
Have a look at your code here:

```
    else if (name.val().match(/^[A-Za-z]+$/))
//change this to else if (!(name.val().match(/^[A-Za-z]+$/)))
    {
     alert("Error, Pattern Doesn't Match");
     return false;
    }
    else
    {
     return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Firebug and set a break point to walk the code, it'll probably give you a hint why your going into the wrong block of code.